# How to setup dbt UI for data lineage?

Tags: dbt

I'm new to the dbt and I'm planning to use dbt cli. One question is how to setup the dbt ui and have such a data lineage graph? I didn't find how to do it here with cli https://docs.getdbt.com/tutorial/create-a-project-dbt-cli.

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

dbt docs might be what you're looking for?

You need to first generate the docs using:

`dbt docs generate`

Then, serve them:

`dbt docs serve`

You'll find that the docs are served locally. Once you open the link in a browser you can see the lineage at the bottom right like so:

[image]

There is more detail here: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/commands/cmd-docs