# How to generate DBT data lineage graphs in client's production environment?

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, dbt, data-lineage

Our project runs on client's infrastructure wherein infra is managed via Kubernetes and Terraform. We automate our jobs using Airflow.

Any Airflow with DBT runs using KubernetesPodOperator provided in Airflow. We plan to create data lineage graphs for each client's tables.

I saw this link

[How to setup dbt UI for data lineage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69550294/how-to-setup-dbt-ui-for-data-lineage)

and using the 2 below commands, I can generate the DBT data docs in my local machine.

```
dbt docs generage
dbt docs serve --port 8081
```

Now I need to generate the same at any client's location. So I have written the DAG as shown below:

```
sync_data_lineage = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace='etl',
                                                 image=f'blotout/dbt-analytics:{TAG_DBT_VERSION}',
                                                 cmds=["/usr/local/bin/dbt"],
                                                 arguments=['docs', 'generate'],
                                                 env_vars=env_var,
                                                 name="sync_data_lineage",
                                                 configmaps=['awskey'],
                                                 task_id="sync_data_lineage",
                                                 get_logs=True,
                                                 dag=dag,
                                                 is_delete_operator_pod=True,
                                                 )

    deploy_lineage_graph = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace='etl',
                                              image=f'blotout/dbt-analytics:{TAG_DBT_VERSION}',
                                              cmds=["/usr/local/bin/dbt"],
                                              arguments=['docs', 'serve', '--port', '8081'],
                                              env_vars=env_var,
                                              name="deploy_lineage_graph",
                                              configmaps=['awskey'],
                                              task_id="deploy_lineage_graph",
                                              get_logs=True,
                                              dag=dag,
                                              is_delete_operator_pod=True,
                                              )

sync_data_lineage >> deploy_lineage_graph
```

Now the first task runs successfully but when second one runs, it does not find catalog.json which is created by first task 'sync_data_lineage'. The reason being once the first DBT command runs and generates the catalog.json, the pod is destroyed. The second task runs in a second pod and hence not able to deploy docs as catalog.json in missing from first step.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I am not using any of this (neither airflow nor k8s), but a wild guess: would running `dbt docs generate && dbt docs serve --port 8081` (so both commands in the same pod) fix this, if the issue is related to missing the `catalog.json`?

Comment: I think you might need to mount your pods to a volume and persist the files at least temporarily until the lineage runs and then you can scrap it.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving DBT artifacts on S3 or other external storage.

Answer (score 0):

`dbt docs generate` command will generate project documentation (including lineage) and store it under `target/` directory.

`dbt docs serve --port 8081` will start an HTTP server serving the static files. Running it in a kubernetes operator will start a pod that doesn't complete it's work.

Since the documentation is a static site, it can be served using any hosting solution. The Airflow operator can be modified to run a script that automates the process of publishing the contents of `target/` to that server, stores them in an object storage etc.

**EDIT:**

DBT docs on [documentation](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/collaborate/documentation#deploying-the-documentation-site) suggest against using `dbt docs serve`, as it's intended for local/development hosting. Docs also suggest valid alternatives.